# Fortran 90 Error: input requires too much data

Tags: error-handling, fortran, fortran90

I have the following code:

```
if (complex) then
read(unitvector) (CoefC(jl),jl=1,NV)
endif
```

Where a user indicates if the data is a collection of complex numbers. Now, if the user indicates that it is, but it actually isn't, i get error 67 (input requires too much data). How can i trap that, so i can write that perhaps a user made a mistake. I was thinking it would look something like:

```
read(unitvector, ioStat=iocplx) (CoefC(jl),jl=1,NV)
```

but where would i put the "if" to check for the error?

Comment: Not answering your question, but a simpler syntax for the read is read(unitvector) CoefC(1:NV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the overall logic of the program, we cannot tell you the best way for you from such small code snippet. You can try something like (not tested):

```
if (complex) then
  read(unitvector, ioStat=iocplx) (CoefC(jl),jl=1,NV) 
  if (iocplx/=0) stop "Error reading the complex data."
end if
```

or

```
if (complex) then
  read(unitvector, ioStat=iocplx) (CoefC(jl),jl=1,NV) 
  if (iocplx/=0) then
     write(*,*) "Error reading the complex data, triung real."
     complex = .false.
     backspace(unitvector)
     read(unitvector, ioStat=ioreal) (CoefR(jl),jl=1,NV)
     if (ioreal/=0) then
       stop "Error reading real data."
     end if
  end if
end if
```

But you really did not specify what you want, stop the program and write a meaningful message? Read data some other way? Everything is possible and we do not have a crystal ball.

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure about the syntax. Since the read(unitvector) (CoefC(jl),jl=1,NV) is like a self sustained loop, i wasn't sure where to stick the IF statement, for it to be executed first before the program crashes. The first part of your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.